# CakePHP - Searching 3 tables efficiently using JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, join

I'm currently trying to implement a search engine function in my CakePHP site, trying to return information from 3 tables efficiently. The main usage will be numeric searches, free text will be extremely minimal and as such I'm not trying to optimise for this scenario.

```
Companies hasMany Products
Products hasMany Prices
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to use something like the following function in the Products controller (this won't work due to distant relationships):

```
$results = $this->Product->find('all', array(
    //conditions can be defined against all 3 tables
    'conditions' =>. array(
        'company.name LIKE' => '%'.$search_term.'%',
        'product.feature' => $product_feature,
        'price.price <' => $price
    ),
    //fields restricted against all 3 tables
    'fields' => array(
        'company.name',
        'product.feature',
        'price.price'
    )
));
```

I've tried using Containable behaviour to include the three models but to no avail.

I believe the solution lies with JOINS but my experience with these is limited, I've tried code similar to the following within the find function above:

```
'joins' => array(
    array(
        'table' => 'companies',
        'alias' => 'Company',
        //tried a mix of joins (LEFT, RIGHT, INNER)
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'conditions' => array(
            'Company.id = Product.company_id'
        )
    ),
    array(
        'table' => 'prices',
        'alias' => 'Price',
        //tried a mix of joins (LEFT, RIGHT, INNER)
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'conditions' => array(
            'Price.product_id = Product.id'
        )
    ),
),
'recursive' => 1,
```

Edit: The result of the above joins is that when i specify the price in the conditions or fields that it can't be found, I tried changing the names such as Product.Price.price to account for the one to many relationship but still without luck.

I'd appreciate any help in finding a solution!

Comment: Well, what is not working with these joins? There must be an error message or some kind of result. Further, if you want to effectively search something (even none relational data) you should build a search index, the recommended solution here is to use Elastic Search, Lucene or Sphinx for that purpose.

Comment: I've updated my post to include the errors I receive, it doesn't like searching more than 2 of the tables, I can build a search that will look across Company and Products or Products and Price but not Company and Products and Price. I'll look at the three items you've suggested, but in the mean time it would be great if I could get a working solution without that. To note: free text search will be a small part of the solution, it will be mainly integer based searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I prefer less code** with cake model/table naming convention (db table `products` - model name `Product`, db table `prices` - model name `Price`) for further project management. It's looks like You want to do:

```
$results = $this->Product->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array(
        'Company.name',
        'Product.feature',
        'Price.price'
    ),
    'joins' => array(
        'LEFT JOIN companies AS Company ON Product.company_id = Company.id
         LEFT JOIN prices AS Price ON Product.id = Price.product_id'
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'Company.name LIKE' => '%'.$search_term.'%',
        'Product.feature' => $product_feature,
        'Price.price <' => $price
    ),

 ));
```

but **if** You want to get **products with** Your **all criteria** (company and price) **only**, You should use `INNER JOIN`, and `GROUP BY` Product (`group` option).

Also, if You want to get all products with many prices and companies result and You set/link model relations, You can use `contain` option, like:

```
$contain = array(
    'Company' => array(
        // ...
        'conditions' => array('Company.name LIKE' => '%'.$search_term.'%'),
        // ...
    ),
    'Price' => array(
        // you can set: 'fields' => array('id', ...),
        'conditions' => array('Price.price <' => $price),
        // you can set order: 'ordder' => '....'                
    )
);

$this->Product->attach('Containable');
$post = $this->Product->find('all', array(
    // ...
    'contain' => $contain,
    'conditions' => array('Product.feature' => $product_feature),
    // ...
));
```

So You will get all products with `feature => $product_feautre`, and You get `LEFT JOIN` companies and prices to this products.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this, I've tested the first solution and there's no error but it ignores the Price conditions and also price field limitations. The containable solution again contains no error, but it doesn't produce a list based on all conditions, each condition is treated separately. I believe the first solution is closest, any ideas on modifying that to restrict itself to the price conditions in addition to products and companies?

Comment: for all conditions use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`. INNER JOIN show results with match all your conditions, LEFT JOIN show all products and empty fields of companies and prices if not match the conditions.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually working with both LEFT and INNER. Regarding limiting fields. When I limit fields for company and plan it's working fine, when I limit by price it does return the listed fields, but it also returns an extra array of the entire row i.e. [Price] => Array ( [price] => 1.00 [term] => 1 [0] => Array ( [id] => 89 [product_id] => 65 [price] => 1.00 [term] => 1 [setup_cost] => 0.99 [url] => [created] => 2014-03-18 23:42:09 [modified] => 2014-03-18 23:42:09 ) ) Any idea why this would be the case?

Comment: Try to set `recursive => -1`, then You will get only one model/table. When You have relations in your models `hasMany`/`belongsTo` etc. without setting `recursive` or `contain` - cake will join this models/tables to your query too.

Comment: If I do that, it returns an unknown column name in the where clause against Company.name, it's as if the joins aren't working without recursive.

Comment: I fixed this by moving Company.name out of the conditions array and into the join, thanks for all your help.