# CakePHP - Grouping and deduping results from JOINs

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, cakephp

I'm currently trying to implement a search engine function in my CakePHP site, trying to return information from 3 tables efficiently. The main usage will be numeric searches, free text will be extremely minimal and as such I'm not trying to optimise for this scenario.

The problem I'm having is trying to Group results from one table to reduce duplicate information, sorry for the long post!

The tables being used are as follows:

```
Companies hasMany Products
Products hasMany Prices
```

I have a successful method of returning results from all 3 tables based on conditions for any or all of the tables using the below code (as a result of the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22529998/cakephp-searching-3-tables-efficiently-using-join))

```
    //configure search conditions
    $options['conditions'] = array(
        'Company.name LIKE' => '%'.$search_term.'%',
        'Product.feature' => $product_feature,
        'Price.price <' => $price
    );

    //configure search fields
    $options['fields'] = array(
        'Company.id',
        'Company.name',
        'Product.id',
        'Product.feature',
        'Price.id',
        'Price.price',
    );

    //configure search joins
    $options['joins'] = array(
        'INNER JOIN prices as Price ON Price.product_id = Product.id INNER JOIN companies as Company ON Product.company_id = Company.id'
    );

    //configure recursion
    $options['recursive'] = -1;

    //configure pagination options
    $this->Paginator->settings = $options;

    //retrieve results and pass to view
    $this->set('results', $this->Paginator->paginate('Product'));
```

The results returned from the above query are like follows:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Company] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [name] => Company 1
            )

        [Product] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [feature] => true
            )

        [Price] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [price] => 1.00
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Company] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [name] => Company 1
            )

        [Product] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [feature] => true
            )

        [Price] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [price] => 2.00
            )

    )
)
```

As you can see the company and product information in the above instance is duplicated, ideally I'd like the information to be returned as follows:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Company] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [name] => Company 1
            )

        [Product] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [feature] => true
            )

        [Price] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [price] => 1.00
                    )
                [1] => Array
                    (       
                        [id] => 2
                        [price] => 2.00
                    )
            )
    )
)
```

I managed to create this by using the following settings:

```
    //configure search joins
    $options['joins'] = array(
        'INNER JOIN prices as Price ON Price.product_id = Product.id'
    );

    //configure recursion
    $options['recursive'] = 1;
```

The above continues to work returning only results that meet all conditions for Companies and Products, but in the Prices array it returns all prices for the specified Companies and Products rather than just those that meet the conditions.

For example: a condition of "max price of 1"  with the above information would return all companies and products that have a price that meets the condition "max price of 1", the problem being it would just then list all prices even those that don't meet the condition, as follows:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Company] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [name] => Company 1
            )

        [Product] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [feature] => true
            )

        [Price] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [price] => 1.00
                    )
                //the below array result shouldn't be here as it doesn't meet the condition "max price of 1"
                [1] => Array
                    (       
                        [id] => 2
                        [price] => 2.00
                    )
            )
    )
)
```

**Question:** How can I modify the above code to return information with grouped results from the Price table to reduce duplicates, but only those that actually meet the specified conditions?

**Bonus:** If there is a more efficient way of performing the above search I'd be very interested to know. Even though the above takes 0ms with the limited number of results I have on my local machine CakePHP is still telling me "maybe slow" which I believe is as a result of the joins.

Comment: I don't know cakephp, but is this: `'Price.price <' => $price` with the `<` correct? Obviously there is scope for `<` (instead of `=`) to return multiple prices.

Comment: Yes in cakephp this is the method used for including conditions, so all prices less than the $price variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Split the problem in two

What you describe is:

- Find all products with *at least one* product matching the conditions
- For those products, return the products with matching price data.

The associations you describe are:

```
Company hasMany Product 
Product hasMany Price
```

OR:

```
Product belongsTo Company
Price belongsTo Product
```

Expressed like that it may be obvious that a find on Product will join Company if recursive is 0 or greater. That removes one manual join.

### Ensure the right products are returned

First ensure you obtain the list of products you want. from what is described there's a choice either set things up using joins:

```
$options['recursive'] = 0; // temporary

$options['conditions'] = array(
    'Company.name LIKE' => '%'.$search_term.'%',
    'Product.feature' => $product_feature,
    'Price.price <' => $price
);

//configure search fields
$options['fields'] = array(
    'Distinct Product.id',
    'Product.feature',
    'Company.id',
    'Company.name',
    #'Price.id', No
    #'Price.price', No
);

$options['joins'][] = 'INNER JOIN prices as PriceFilter ON Price.product_id = Product.id';
```

Or Conditions:

```
$options['recursive'] = 0; // temporary

$options['conditions'] = array(
    'Company.name LIKE' => '%'.$search_term.'%',
    'Product.feature' => $product_feature,
    "WHERE EXISTS (select * from prices where prices.product_id = Product.id AND prices.price < $price)"
);

$options['fields'] = array(
    'Product.id',
    'Product.feature',
    'Company.id',
    'Company.name',
    #'Price.id', No
    #'Price.price', No
);
```

Note that there are now no extra joins in the primary find/paginate call.

In both of these examples there should be *one* query (plus a count) executed, without any price data.

### Use containable to get matching prices

[Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) makes it easier to manage what queries are executed and what scope of results are returned. In this case all that's required is to add Price data to the resultset - and filter the prices. A complete example demonstrating the use of the [contain](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#using-containable-with-pagination) option:

```
public $paginate = array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Company',
        'Price' => array()
    ),
    'fields' => array(
        'Product.id',
        'Product.feature',
        'Company.id',
        'Company.name'
    )
);

function whatever() {
    ...

    $this->paginate['contain']['Price']['conditions']['Price.price <'] = $price;

    $conditions = array(
        'Company.name LIKE' => '%'.$search_term.'%',
        'Product.feature' => $product_feature,
        "WHERE EXISTS (select * from prices where prices.product_id = Product.id AND prices.price < $price)"
    );

    $result = $this->paginate('Product', $conditions);

    ...
}
```

This should result in *two* queries (plus a count), and the data structure you're looking for; including price data.

### Maybe slow

> Even though the above takes 0ms, [...] CakePHP is still telling me "maybe slow"

Debug kit is not interogating the database, to determine if a query is "maybe slow" it is a [simple test](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit/blob/master/View/Helper/ToolbarHelper.php#L179-L190) for:

- Query took more than 0ms
- Query took more than 1ms per result
- Query took more than `threshold` (which defaults to 20ms)

From checking the code it should never flag a 0ms query as "maybe slow" - but it's not a problem if it does.

As with all database activity it's a good idea to run explain on the db, add any missing indexes and consider different query structures that would return the same data.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed response AD7six, I'll try this out later tonight.

Comment: Thanks again for this AD7six, I've tested the above containable and it works great. One problem I have run into though is that my paginate sort functions no longer work as the prices are contained in a subquery so users can't sort by price lowest to highest etc. Do you know anyway around this or am I going to have to use my previous solution and just manipulate the data to remove duplicates? In this instance it might be quite complicated because I would want to sort based on the lowest of all valid returned prices for a particular plan.

Comment: That sounds confused. It's not clear what kind of index you're presenting to the user. If you paginate using the recommended example, there will always be n Products (where n is the pagination limit). If you use a join, there will be 1 to n depending on how many prices each product has. To sort, you need the field being sorted on to be in the main query; it's not possible to have a single query returning all data and "reduce duplicate information". Therefore you probably want the join, to _not_ do anything about "duplicates" (or handle them in the view layer).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm trying to return the products with a list of the associated prices. I'd like to display a field along the lines of (from £x) and sort based on that value. I managed to do this through a virtual field using $this->Product->virtualFields = array('price' => 'SELECT MIN(price) FROM prices WHERE prices.product_id = Product.id') and it seems to work.